# rewrite url /v1/json/acount to ?v=v1&f=json&t=account

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite this url `api.domain.com/v1/json/account?id=123` to `api.domain.com?id=123&v=v1&f=json&t=account`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(api)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(\?%{QUERY_STRING})?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /?%{QUERY_STRING}&v=%1&f=%2&t=%3 [L]
```

Comment: 1) Do you need to have that check for specific domain name (just asking); 2) Do you need to redirect ONLY this SPECIFIC URL (I mean, `v1` always be `v1`, `json` always be `json`) or you need a bit more generic rule (where `json` may become `xml`); 3) Why `QSA` flag is not good (are you afraid that user may provide his own `&v=` value etc? 4) Where this rule will be placed -- in .htaccess or in config file (e.g. `<VirtualHost>` section)? 5) You want rewrite, not redirect?

Comment: jep.. this rewrite only has to work for this specific subdomain.. and no, this is only an example.. I want a rewrite

Comment: As I understand you have resolved it yourself. Good :)

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?v=$1&f=$2&t=$3 [QSA,R,L]`

That should do it - you were very close. You are welcome to add your `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` one line above it (I have not tested that for you).

Let the Query-String-Append (QSA) flag do the hard work for you :). See the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) if you're curious about how that works.

Edit: Just to clarify, the only line you need to accomplish this is the one I have posted, it obviates your second RewriteCond and RewriteRule and collapses it into one statement. You may choose to add a single additional RewriteCond above it to check the value of %{HTTP_HOST}.

Comment: it doesn't work.. `api.domain.com/v1/json/account/?id=123` is redirected to `/v1/json/account/`.. my rewrite looks like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(api)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?v=$1&f=$2&t=$3 [QSA,L]`

Comment: It definitely works, I tested it before I posted: /v1/json/account becomes /?v=v1&f=json&t=account and /v1/json/account/?id=123 becomes /?v=v1&f=json&t=account&id=123. Two things: 1) you removed the R flag from the rule (make it [QSA,R,L], you need it) and 2) just for testing purposes, remove the RewriteCond to ensure that is not your problem.

Comment: if you use the flag QSA, then the query string will override any of the v, f or t vars (if the query string contains any of them)

Comment: now the rewrite looks like this `RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?v=$1&f=$2&t=$3 [QSA,R,L]` but still the same... I'm requsting `api.domain.com/v1/json/account/?id=123`

Comment: the rewritecond line is escaped

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^api\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /?%{QUERY_STRING}&v=%1&f=%2&t=%3 [L]
```